# Program using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c

I have the below program in C. How did `p[0][0]` become 1? Can somebody help in understanding?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int i,j;
int **p=(int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
  p[0]=(int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
  p[1]=p[0];
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
     {
            p[i][j]=i+j;
            printf("%d,%d,%d",i,j,p[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
     }
 printf("%d,%d,%d",i,j,p[0][0]);
}
```

the output is as below

```
0,0,0
0,1,1
1,0,1
1,1,2
2,2,1
```

Comment: Note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You allocate 2-pointers, now you must allocate a block of 2-int for each pointer...

Comment: `p[1]` is `p[0]`, so when you made the assignment `p[1][0] = 1`, that was equivalent to `p[0][0] = 1`.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `main()`  In C, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding, please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

The same pointer is assigned to `p[0]` and `p[1]`. This means `p[0]` and `p[1]` points at the same array. Therefore updates done via `p[1]` is also visible via `p[0]`.

In the second iteration of outer `for` loop, `1` is assigned to `p[1][0]`. This makes `p[0][0]` to be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

After the following lines of code:

```
int **p=(int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
p[0]=(int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
p[1]=p[0];
```

this is what you have in memory:

```
   int **        int *           int
   +---+         +---+           +---+
p: |   | ------> |   | p[0] -+-> |   | p[0][0], p[1][0]
   +---+         +---+       |   +---+
                 |   | p[1] -+   |   | p[0][1], p[1][1]
                 +---+           +---+
```

`p[0]` and `p[1]` point to the same 2-element array, so anything you write to `p[0][i]` is reflected in `p[1][i]` and vice-versa.

What you *probably* meant to do was something like

```
int **p = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p ); // cast not necessary, sizeof *p == sizeof (int *)
p[0] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p[0] );
p[1] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p[1] );
```

which would give you

```
   int **        int *            int 
   +---+         +---+            +---+
p: |   | ------> |   | p[0] ----> |   | p[0][0]
   +---+         +---+            +---+
                 |   | p[1] --+   |   | p[0][1]
                 +---+        |   +---+
                              |
                              |   +---+ 
                              +-> |   | p[1][0]
                                  +---+
                                  |   | p[1][1]
                                  +---+
```